# Remove/strip specific Html tag and replace using NotePad++

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

Here is my text:

```
<h3>#6</h2>
Is he eating a lemon?

</div>
```

I have a few of them in my articles the #number is always different also the text is always different.

I want to make this out of it:

```
<h3>#6 Is he eating a lemon?</h3>
```

I tried it via regex in notepad++ but I am still very new to this:

My Search:

```
<h3>.*?</h2>\r\n.*?\r\n\r\n</div>
```

Also see [here](http://pastebin.com/qPQtVtYz).

Now it is always selecting the the right part of the text.

How does my replace command need to look like now to get an output like above?

Comment: your regex pattern right now is doubled. Is that a typo?

Comment: that is a typo, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your original regex to capture the text you want in groups, like this:

```
<h3>(.*?)</h2>\r\n(.*?)\r\n\r\n</div>
    (   )         (   ) 
//  ^             ^     These are your capture groups
```

You can then access these groups with the `\1` and `\2` tokens respectively.

So your replace pattern would look like:

```
<h3>\1 \2</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search could be `<h3>(.*)<\/h2>\r\n(.*)\r\n\r\n<\/div>`
and the replace is `<h3>$1 $2</h3>`, where $1 and $2 represent the strings captured in the parentheses.